# Arduino IDE gives error a1 is not declared

Tags: arduino-nano

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5);
```

in this code the error given by IDE is 'A1' was not declared in this scope.
So whats the problem please help

Comment: Is that your whole code?

Comment: in Arduino IDE? with Nano selected in Tools menu?

Comment: Try using the GPIO numbers ```LiquidCrystal lcd(14,15,16,17,18,19);``` rather than the analog pin numbers. https://i2.wp.com/christianto.tjahyadi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/nano.jpg has the pinout diagram.